# LevelHelper Universal Project Not Done

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have created Universal project in cocos2d Level Helper and create body of object in Sprite Helper but when I run the project in XCode simulator the physics simulation is not working.

I tried to check but the LHSprite.body is Null.

Help me to how I make Universal project in Level Helper.

Answer (score 0):

1. You mentioned about Universal project, does your project currently work on ipad or iphone?
2. Make sure your physics objects are not all static. you can change it in spritehelper or levelhelper
3. Do remember setup **Physic Boundaries** and Game World Size in Levelhelper properly.

Actually, I think the most possible reason could be **Physic Boundaries**:-)

Comment: When i create project only for IPad it works well with the same object but in Universal it not work, I check the Boundaries and also body type they are perfect but also it is not working.

Comment: hmm... that's odd, I am using levelhelper 1.4.7 and spritehelper 1.7.5. just wondering if it is because your version is bit old. BTW,   do you have both images asset for ipad and iphone (usually using "Save SD" in spritehelper to do so). do you setup properly to make cocos2d to load different asset when it's running on different device ?